# Changing SharePoint form library auto increment manually

Tags: sharepoint, forms, auto-increment

is it possible to manually increase the autoincrement of ID column to another number in a SharePoint forms library? I need to do it once. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an item then delete it.

Edit:
If you need to increment more than one, use the Data Sheet view and do the same in bulk.

Comment: What happens if people have email notifications set up for new items in that list? :-)

Comment: The interweb explodes :-) or

Central Administration > Application Management > Web Application General Settings  > Alerts > Alerts on this server are: Off